# AttachCurrentThread crash in multi threads JNI after moving to Android L release

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have implemented a service which is invoked by system server during the boot-up.

My service has JNI implementation which creates another thread.
The reason for having another thread is to have the capability of canceling operation while monitoring the call back.

This mechanism worked well in Android Kitkat release but it crashes in Android L.

Between two threads, I stored the JavaVM* that I get from GetJavaVM(env) to a static global variable. Of course, this shared data is protected by pthread mutex.

I have tried the following so far, but all of them below still crashed :

1) Used JavaVM* I get from JNI onLoad() function by store it to global

2) In the new thread, as there is only one JavaVM running on Android, get the vm from calling  android::AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM();

3) Stored the vm information in the main thread after calling NewGlobalRef(). And saved that reference to the shared data. The new thread used the reference from NewGlobalRef().

Does anyone know what is significantly changed in JNI environment on Android L release?

UPDATE :

Debugged further and the solution I mentioned 1) or 2) should have worked.
The actual issue was due to the garbage collection running more frequently. So the HAL pointer I kept was not valid any more...

These links were helpful!!!

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: I would try to start the thread from Java and only then use it from another thread. In Android, Java threads = native threads.

Comment: I have seen a similar problem in IIRC iOS, the reason was that iOS used TLS (thread-local storage) for i/o, and the file could be read only from the thread that has opened it. Maybe it was not iOS, but you see the point.

Comment: @18446744073709551615, thanks for the reply. I may need the design change but I would like to resolve the problem first... I am more experienced with posix thread than Java.

Answer (score 0):

What has changed with L release is the move to ART that is less flexible than Dalvik regarding errors.

It's perfectly fine to share JavaVM* across threads, you should keep it this way.

However, what are you doing later with this JavaVM* ?

JNIEnv* has to be retrieved and used from the same thread and must not be used across threads. To use JNIEnv*, a thread must have been attached to the VM (using `AttachCurrentThread`).
Threads also have to be detached using `DetachCurrentThread` before they exit.

Comment: My service supports operations of run_hardware, cancel_hardware and notification when the request is done. So in order to do that, when the service gets the request, I creates another thread to wait for notification. So the main thread is not blocked to handle a cancel request.

Comment: With JavaVM*, i call attachCurrentThread(), from that, I will get the environment I can use for callback later. What can be done for ART change in Android L release?